# Join a non-child thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

Normally you call join() on a thread from it's parent to wait for it to finish.

Is it allowed for a thread to call join() on another thread that is not it's child? And if it is, should this ever be used?

Comment: It's okay, there's nothing preventing that.

Comment: The C++ standard has no concept of "child" threads or "parent" threads, there are just threads. Any thread can join any other (except itself).